# JBoss eventually stops responding to request, but no OOME

Tags: jboss

I'm having an issue with jboss server. when i run jboss server, it stops responding( no fixed time, so cannot predict when will it stop responding after start) after that it doesn't writes anything in log file. my problem is similar to the problem described on jboss community, link given below but it doesn't have the answer. please help.
http://community.jboss.org/message/526193

--Ravi

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your jboss server is running out of threads to allocate and is waiting for a new one to become available. Try triggering a thread dump (ctrl-\) and see if you find any threads suspiciously locked and waiting in some of your code. Quite possibly you have a deadlock or memory leak somewhere in your code which is causing old threads to lock up and never be released.

Alternatively try what the guy you linked to did, i.e. increasing the amount of threads available.

edit: For some more basic advice, [this post](http://www.correlsense.com/cto-blog/top-3-reasons-an-application-hangs/) might be of use to you.

Comment: Hi wds, thanks for reply, 
 after server hang , we did saw IO dump, memory dump, network stats, server logs but everything was normal, and server was not logging anything to log file and also there were no exception in log, so we have no clue why server was hung. we are trying to create same kind of load on server and replicate the issue. thanks again for reference doc.